# Entity type 'myViewModel' has no key defined. This wasn't happening yesterday

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository, viewmodel, code-first

Ok, so I'm a little confused. I've had an mvc 4 application that has been working fine for weeks now up until this morning when I tried to run it (without having made any changes since the last time I ran it yesterday) and now I'm getting this error saying EntityType 'MyViewModel' has no key defined. Define a key for this EntityType. The error is popping up in my generic repository class here:

```
public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }
```

My application generates the database using the EF code-first method and when I look at the table definition, it recognizes the ID property as my primary key so I don't get what is going on here.

GenericRepository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
using SourceMvc.Models;
using SourceMvc.DAL;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace SourceMvc.DAL
{
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal StqmContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(StqmContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

}
}
```

my View Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SourceMvc.Models;

namespace SourceMvc.DAL
{
public class QuotesViewModel
{
    //properties
    public General_Info     General_Info    { get; private set; }

    // Constructors

    public QuotesViewModel()
    {

    }

    public QuotesViewModel(General_Info general_info)
    {
        General_Info = general_info;
    }
```

And the controller being called when the error is thrown:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using SourceMvc.Models;
using SourceMvc.DAL;

namespace SourceMvc.Controllers
{
    public class VendorController : Controller
    {

        UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

        internal IGeneral_Info_Repository general_info_repository;

        public VendorController()
        {
            this.general_info_repository = new General_Info_Repository(new StqmContext());
        }

        internal VendorController(IGeneral_Info_Repository general_info_repository)
        {
            this.general_info_repository = general_info_repository;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Vendor/

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult InitiateQuote()
        {
            return View();

        }

        //
        // POST: /Vendor/
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult InitiateQuote(int id = 0)
        {
            /*
             * If the form is filled out correctly 
             * (i.e. an existing quote id # is entered)
             * redirect the user to Vendor/Details/id
             */
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int ids = id;
                return RedirectToAction("Overview", "Vendor", new { id = ids });
            }

            return View();
        }

        ////WHEN I SUBIT THE QUOTE ID AND THE OVERVIEW PAGE IS SUPPOSED TO LOAD,
        ///THAT'S WHEN I GET THE ERROR
        //
        // GET: /Vendor/Overview/id

        public ActionResult Overview(int id = 0)
        {
            General_Info general_info = unitOfWork.General_Info_Repository.GetByID(id);
            return View(new QuotesViewModel(general_info));
        }
```

I honestly have no idea what's causing this because like I said, this worked yesterday, and has been working for weeks. Thank's in advance to anyone who tries to help.

And here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[General_Info] (
[ID]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Open_Quote]      DATETIME       NOT NULL,
[Customer_Name]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[OEM_Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Qty]             INT            NOT NULL,
[Quote_Num]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Fab_Drawing_Num] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Rfq_Num]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Rev_Num]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.General_Info] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Your controller code is confusing. If you are using the `unitOfWork.General_Info_Repository`, then what is the purpose of the internal `general_info_repository` that you initialize in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case i think you might have changed the primary key constraints in your view model or your sql table; cause primary key has to be defined to use Find() on your EF generated models.

Comment: What can I do to fix that? When I expand my table in server explorer it shows that it recognizes ID as the key which code-first assigns automatically.

Comment: Make sure your table has primary key defined and then update your EF model, rest has to work with no changes required.

Comment: I've added a copy of my table definition above

Comment: Hey serene, I've got everything up and running again. The solution was to add public int ID {get; set;} to the top of my viewmodel. Given that that got everything up and running again, I'm curious as to why this has worked for weeks without that included in my viewmodel. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.